# Lucene create index for words with umlauts in stratio

Tags: java, cassandra, lucene, stratio, cassandra-lucene-index

I have a similar issue like described [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451276/german-ue-u-conversion-in-lucene). I would like to use something like the [GermanNormilizationFilter](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/de/GermanNormalizationFilter.html) to have a conversion for umlauts like 'ue' -> 'ü' and vice versa.

I use the cassandra stratio plugin and would like to create the index with a cql statement like in the [official examples](https://github.com/Stratio/cassandra-lucene-index/blob/branch-3.0.10/doc/documentation.rst#example)

Answer (score 0):

Basicly, you want to use a part of the [lucene german analyzer](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/releases/lucene-solr/5.5.3/lucene/analysis/common/src/java/org/apache/lucene/analysis/de/GermanAnalyzer.java) but not all.

In cassandra-lucene-index you can use a [custom analyzer](https://github.com/Stratio/cassandra-lucene-index/blob/branch-3.0.10/doc/documentation.rst#analyzers) just generating a jar and including it in cassandra lib folder.

By the way, as you only want a part of German analyzer functionality you can build you own custom based on German analyzer just only editing some lines.

If you close look at [lucene German analyzer code](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/releases/lucene-solr/5.5.3/lucene/analysis/common/src/java/org/apache/lucene/analysis/de/GermanAnalyzer.java#L141-L147) you can see that you only need to edit(remove/comment) some lines in `createComponents` method.